# How to convert date (yyyy-MM-dd) to integer value respecting temporal order in Java

Tags: java, function, date

I have a graph where a subset vertices are dates, other verices have weight 0. I want to put integer cost on the edges depending on the weight of its end vertex dates, such that, iff date(vertex v) < date(vertex w) (i.e., a previous fate in temporal order), then weight(edge on v) < weight(edge on w). Is there any such function in Java?

Comment: Can't you convert the date to long (milliseconds) and use that?

Comment: Why not convert to Unix time as a long?

Comment: Date d = new Date(); unixtime = d.getTime();  unixtime=unixtime/1000; Is this the recommendation?

Comment: You can see the answers. You don't need to divide by 1000 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If your date is stored in strings of the form yyyy-MM-dd as you implied, just sort the strings with the String.compareTo() method.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, you can use [getTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) method (if you're using Java `Date` class) to get the milliseconds. This method

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

Comment: I think Calendar is supposed to have superseded Date in many respects, something like Calendar.getTimeInMillis() should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your date to UTC milliseconds, this gives you a long value, representing the number of milliseconds since midnight 1.1.1970 UT.

For example `java.util.Data` has a method `getTimeStamp()`.

Most (I think evry)  other solution has drawbacks: (Strings needs more mem storage, slower, Timezone problems).

Comment: getTime() is a legal method, but Eclipse is showing getTimeStamp() is not. But the functionality is the same, right?